# Refactoring static methods into instance methods in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

How can I refactor

```
class Plugh {
    static void foo(Bar bar);
}
```

into

```
class Bar {
    void foo();
}
```

using Eclipse? IOW make the static methods into instance methods of one of the arguments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the "static" keyword and then do the "Move Method" refactoring.  It should offer "Bar" as a target class.

(It seems crazy to me that Eclipse only does this for non-static methods, but that is the way it works.  Seems like a bug to me.  Maybe I should work up a contribution to fix it, instead of just complaining about it!  ;-)

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer but I'm afraid I alreadt tagged the other.

Comment: +1 from me, too, @peter.murray.rust - please go ahead and accept this one.  (you can just click the hollow checkbox at this one to change which one's accepted).  It's more important to have the best answer accepted than the earliest.

Comment: This isn't working for me on Eclipse Mars: I delete the `static` keyword and then (whether I save the file or not) when I try *Refactor | Move*, Eclipse tells me "This method cannot be moved, since no possible targets have been found." Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's a fully automated way to do this, but what I would do is to make the body of `Plugh.foo()` call `bar.foo()`, then use Quick Fix (control-1) to create `Bar.foo()`, then cut & paste the (rest of) the body of `Plugh.foo()` into `Bar.foo()`.

Then inline all calls to `Plugh.foo()`, and do an initial assignment inside `Bar.foo()`: `Bar bar = this;`, then inline the local (and probably clean up all the `this.`'s in the method).

Comment: +1 Thanks. Your ideas are certainly better than what I currently do. Pity - it seems a fairly strightforward thing to implement (after all some other languages have a `self` argument instead of `this` and that's  more or less what we're doing

Comment: It may be easier to first move the static method, as a static method, to Bar.  That move is an automated refactoring, and the conversion from static just seems a little cleaner, although I can't point to any reason why.

Comment: see also @JeffGrigg which seems cleaner

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your code to this:

   ```
   class Plugh {
       static void foo(Bar bar) { bar.foo(); }
   }
   ```
2. Then `inline` the method `Plugh.foo(...)`.
   All calls of `Plugh.foo(...)` will be replaced by `barInstance.foo();`.
   `barInstance` can be called anything in the calling code. It will be properly replaced.